# Topology awareness of Cassandra Drivers in php, java, python, node.js

Tags: java, php, python, node.js, cassandra

I'm just being curious. Are Cassandra drivers aware of the topology? Meaning that the driver knows which rack is the closest one and which node is most likely to hold the data and has a low latency to reduce response time of requests? Or is every driver aware of this? Which libraries would you recommend?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's an interesting question.  My guess would be no, because in the drivers I've used (Ruby, Python, node.js) you supply a `hosts` array.  If the server just chose the fastest from among the hosts, you'd have a hotspot of just one node handling all the requests (at least initially).  The whole point of cassandra is to spread the load so I'd assume it's just doing round-robin.

Comment: No drivers knows where the data is going to be, that's the whole advantage of the distributed architecture as well.  The nodes themselves have agreed on a primary key hash range, so they know, which means your data is at most one hop away.  Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to try to make the client driver do all the logic that the server topology does to save one little hop, especially considering the driver might not be supplied all the `hosts`, or even a seed node host.

Comment: Having real time requirements one hop may mean a few ms, which you could safe having some logic in the driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [DataStax drivers for Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax) come with various load balancing options in the form of pluggable policies. Just to give you some examples:

1. smart request routing based on tokens: `TokenAwarePolicy`
2. DC awareness: `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy`
3. latency awareness: `LatencyAwarePolicy`

There are probably other drivers that support some of these load balancing options, but I don't know all of them :-).

Comment: Python driver does not have LatencyAwarePolicy. https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PYTHON-121